# AWS: Pod replicas are automatically scaled down to zero in EKS

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, autoscaling, aws-auto-scaling

I have an EKS cluster in which I am running my application. The node group attached is Managed node group. The problem is if I am not using my application for few hours then my deployment replicas are automatically scaled down to zero.
I checked everything. There is no scaling policy attached to it.
Every time if I want to see run my app I need to scale up the deployment manually. I want to stop this automatic down-scaling.

Comment: Does your deployment config still has `replicas: 1` or what is changing your config?

Comment: @Jonas the config is still showing replicas: 1. but it is automatically scaling down to zero when not in use for 1-2 hours.

Comment: Is there enough nodes? this does not sound like a kubernetes thing, but something related to the nodes. Are there any available nodes when you say "scaled down"?

Comment: @Jonas Yes there are enough nodes. Even there are extra nodes. I don't think it is because of node unavailability.